# Mathematical Modelling of Wireless Power Transfer

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-engineering, antennas, radio-frequency

I am trying to understand the interaction between a transmitting antenna with a certain transmitting power (denoted PTX in the diagram) and how the radiation pattern of the TX antenna is affected by a RX antenna implanted inside the human body and by the human body itself. The purpose of this is to eventually be able to create a first-order analytical model for power density inside the human body.

[image: Basic System Configuration]

For this system, I am assuming that the dimensions of both antenna are known and that the electrical characteristics of the tissue layers are also known (i.e. permittivity and conductivity). As a simplification, each tissue layer is also assumed to have a fixed dimension (d1, d2 etc. as in the diagram).

I am looking for principles which I can use to mathematically describe the EM wave propagation through the human body, taking into account the effects of the human body and the RX antenna on the radiation pattern of the TX antenna.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: see a review article by Hand: [Modelling the interaction of electromagnetic fields (10 MHz–10 GHz) with the human body: methods and applications](https://sci-hub.st/10.1088/0031-9155/53/16/R01)

Comment: Crossposted from https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/54707/2588

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.